# Inverse of a sequence of random variables in Big O

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, asymptotics

In a proof, the authors use that for a sequence of a random variable $X_n$ with $X_n=O_P(a_n)$, $a_n\rightarrow0$ and $a_n>0$, holds $X_n^{-1}=O_P(a_n^{-1}).$ I am not quite sure how to do that.
My approach was to use the definition of $O_P$ $$\lim_{R\rightarrow\infty}\limsup_{n\rightarrow\infty}\mathbb{P}\left(\frac{\lvert X_n\rvert}{a_n}>R\right)=0.$$
Thank you for the help.

Comment: Note that while $a_n \to 0$, $a_n^{-1} \to \infty$. While you can use big $O$ notations for both $\to 0$ and $\to \infty$, they have different meanings.